# Using TLG10UA03 to send HTTP GET

Tags: arduino, wifi

I am using a TLG10UA03 WiFi interface together with my Arduino board. The intension is to send sensor data to a web server in order to publish it on a web site.
I managed to run the TLG10UA03 as a server, in auto mode as well as in command mode. Now I am trying to run it as a client. I can open a socket, connecting to my web server. But I am not able to send the GET command to the web server. No matter what I try the command seems not to arrive at the server.
Is there anybody out there having some experience with this module?

Comment: When you say *"No matter what I try"* - it would help if you explained exactly what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to add "\r\n" at the end of each line.

```
Serial1.print("GET /arduino.php?data=100 HTTP/1.1\r\n");
Serial1.print("Host: domain.com\r\n");
Serial1.print("Connection: close\r\n");
```

Comment: I'm curious...what makes you think this is the answer to the OP's question? If this is just a suggestion, or if you need clarification from the OP, this should be in a comment to the question rather than posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should first use an AT+ command to set up a socket connection to the host you want to connect to. Then switch to transparant mode and send the GET line. Don't send the Host line, it Will not work.

Comment: It's probably worthwhile adding a bit more detail to your answer, at the moment while useful it reads a bit more like a comment on the previous answer. Stack Exchange is designed so that answers should be able to stand on their own.